# Conformal Map from Upper Half Plane to Region

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find a conformal map from the upper half plane to the region $\{z| |z|<1$ and $Re(z) + Im(z) >1\}$.

I know how to map the upper half plane to the unit disc, so I was hoping to then map the unit disc to this region... But I'm completely stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather start from the region and map to the half plane.
First, $z\mapsto \frac1{z-1}$ moves one of the vertices away to infinity while the two parts of the boundary become straight lines, intersecting at $\frac1{i-1}$ with an angle of $45^\circ$. Thus appending the map $z\mapsto \left(z-\frac1{i-1}\right)^4$ "flattens" this other vertex and you at least have *some* half plane. Rotate to get the right one.

Comment: thanks! one question: how did you know you wanted to raise $(z - \frac{1}{i-1})$ to the fourth power?

Comment: Because $z\mapsto z^4$ multiplies the vertex angle (at $0$) by $4$.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything totally wrong?